# I have a ToolTip but the message text is show up far above the checkBox why is that?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void checkBox3_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     mytip3 = new ToolTip();
     mytip3.UseFading = true;
     mytip3.Show("If Checked The Zipped File Will Be Created Automatic\r\n Once The Process Has Finished", checkBox1, 5000);
}
```

Once my mouse is over the checkbox area i see the text message but the text message if above the checkbox somewhere in the Form.

How can i make it to be shown under the checkbox name ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
mytip3.Show("If Checked The Zipped File Will Be Created Automatic\r\n Once The Process Has Finished", checkBox1,267,170, 5000);
```

Comment: It would be *better* if you got the position from `checkbox.Location.Y + checkbox.Height` for the Y-axis and `checkbox.Location.X` for the X-axis to get it right under the checkbox (and maybe add 5px as an offset between, or whatever). More dynamic if you move the checkbox.